# How to get coordinates(cx, cy) of circles after d3 force collision?

Tags: d3.js, d3-force-directed

I'm trying to get coordinates of circles (cx, cy) after using d3-force collision, but I still got original positions. Are there any ways for getting translated(after collision check) coordinates of circles?

Below is just summary of code.

```
let data = [
{ 'x': 100, 'y': 100, 'radius': 10, cluster: 4 },
{ 'x': 100, 'y': 100, 'radius': 6, cluster: 3 },
{ 'x': 50, 'y': 200, 'radius': 10, cluster: 2 },
{ 'x': 350, 'y': 200, 'radius': 10, cluster: 2 },
{ 'x': 100, 'y': 300, 'radius': 20, cluster: 3 },
{ 'x': 100, 'y': 300, 'radius': 25, cluster: 1 },
{ 'x': 100, 'y': 300, 'radius': 33, cluster: 2 }];

var collisionForce = d3.forceCollide((d) => d.radius).strength(1).iterations(100);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data).alphaDecay(0.01).force('collisionForce', collisionForce)
          .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

 var node = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data)
          .enter().append('circle')
          .attr('r', function (d) {
            return d.radius;
          }).attr('cx', function (d) {
            return d.x;
          }).attr('cy', function (d) {
            return d.y;
          })
          .attr('cluster', d => d.cluster)
          .attr('fill', d => that.palette[d.cluster]);

      function ticked() {
        node.attr('cx', function (d) {
          return d.x;
        })
            .attr('cy', function (d) {
              return d.y;
            });
      }

simulation.on('tick', ticked);
```

Comment: Can you provide a working code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [listen to the `end`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_on) event on a simulation, and then access the final coordinates for the circles by changing the last line of your code to this:

```
simulation
  .on('tick', ticked)
  .on('end', () => {
    d3.selectAll('circle').each(function () {
      const thisD3 = d3.select(this)
      console.log(thisD3.attr('cx'), thisD3.attr('cy'))
    })
  })
```

According to my knowledge, the array passed to `d3.forceSimulation` edits the array in place, so you could also access the `x` and `y` coordinates directly in that array. The key in either case is do it when the simualtion triggers the `end` event.

Hope this helps!